# Web-mode left arrow without the right closing angle bracket

Tags: web-mode, smartparens

When using Elixir html template (.eex) in web-mode, I sometimes need to type code like `<%= for bid <- @bids do %>` . At the moment because the opening left angled bracked is closed immediately with a matching right angled bracket, after I type `<-`, I'm left with a closing angled bracket that I don't need and have to delete.

I need help coming up with a way to prevent the left angled bracket from auto closing.

Below is my current web-mode and smartpatens configs:

**Web-mode**

```
(use-package web-mode
  :ensure t
  :mode (("\\.erb\\'" . web-mode)
         ("\\.mustache\\'" . web-mode)
         ("\\.html?\\'" . web-mode)
         ("\\.eex\\'" . web-mode)
         ("\\.php\\'" . web-mode)
         ("\\.jsx$" . web-mode))
  :init
  (setq web-mode-markup-indent-offset 2
        web-mode-css-indent-offset 2
        web-mode-code-indent-offset 2)
  ;; make web-mode play nice with smartparens
  (setq web-mode-enable-auto-pairing nil)
  ;(setq web-mode-enable-auto-closing nil)
  (setq web-mode-enable-current-element-highlight t)
  (setq web-mode-enable-current-column-highlight t)
  :config
  (sp-with-modes '(web-mode)
    (sp-local-pair "<" nil :actions nil)
    (sp-local-pair "% " " %"
                   :unless '(sp-in-string-p)
                   :post-handlers '(((lambda (&rest _ignored)
                                       (just-one-space)
                                       (save-excursion (insert " ")))
                                     "SPC" "=" "#")))
    (sp-local-pair "<% " " %>" :insert "C-b %")
    (sp-local-pair "<%= " " %>" :insert "C-b =")
    (sp-local-pair "<%# " " %>" :insert "C-b #")
    (sp-local-pair "<-" "")))
```

**Smartparens**

```
(use-package smartparens
  :ensure t
  :hook (prog-mode . smartparens-mode)
  :init
  ;; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23789962/how-to-disable-emacs-highlighting-whitespace-in-parenthesis
  (setq sp-highlight-pair-overlay nil)
  :bind
  (:map smartparens-mode-map
        ("C-M-f" . sp-forward-sexp)
        ("C-M-b" . sp-backward-sexp)
        ("C-M-a" . sp-backward-down-sexp)
        ("C-M-e" . sp-up-sexp)
        ("C-M-w" . sp-copy-sexp)
        ("C-M-k" . sp-change-enclosing)
        ("M-k" . sp-kill-sexp)
        ("C-M-<backspace>" . sp-splice-sexp-killing-backward)
        ("C-S-<backspace>" . sp-splice-sexp-killing-around)
        ("C-]" . sp-select-next-thing-exchange))
  :config
  (require 'smartparens-config)
  (sp-local-pair 'emacs-lisp-mode "'" nil :actions nil)
  (sp-local-pair 'org-mode "[" nil :actions nil)
  (sp-local-pair 'prog-mode "{" nil :post-handlers '((my-create-newline-and-enter-sexp "RET")))
  (sp-local-pair 'prog-mode "(" nil :post-handlers '((my-create-newline-and-enter-sexp "RET"))))
```

Thanks.

Comment: Made simple-paren for this, available from melpa, which comes with explicit keys instead of implicit trigger.

Comment: I'm trying to use your packge without success so far and therefore wondering if I'm doing it right. Below is my config:     ```(use-package simple-paren
  :config
  (simple-paren-define left-pointing-single-arrow ?<-)
  (simple-paren-define angled-bracket-percent-pair ?<% ?%>)
  (simple-paren-define angled-bracket-equal-pair ?<%= ?%>))```

Comment: Please consider a  bug-report at https://github.com/andreas-roehler/simple-paren. README there also tells how to extend the package.

Answer (score 0):

To remove pre-existing pairs, you have to use `:action :rem`, not `:action nil`. There is even an [example in the documentation](https://smartparens.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pair-management.html#removing-pairs).

So this line:

```
    (sp-local-pair "<" nil :actions nil)
```

needs to be changed to:

```
    (sp-local-pair "<" nil :actions :rem)
```

Comment: I tried that before and just tried it again. It gives me an error message ```File mode specification error: (wrong-type-argument consp nil)```